# R - use R code as string in Oracle SQL Query

Tags: sql, r, oracle

I am attempting to execute an Oracle SQL query like so:

```
library("data.table")
library("RODBC")
db = "database"
uid = "my username"
pw = "my password"
lookup = "12345D%"

myconn <- odbcConnect(db, uid, pw)

query_df <- as.data.table(sqlQuery(
    myconn,
    "SELECT *
     FROM tableX
     WHERE tableX.code LIKE '12345D%';"
))
close(myconn)
```

My issue is that it is redundant to define `lookup` before the query and use the value in the query itself.  I would like to just be able to type

```
WHERE tableX.code LIKE lookup
```

and have the value `12345D%` substituted into my query.  I tried substituting `lookup` into the query directly but I received a result with no observations.  Of course it works fine when I put `12345D%` into the query itself but I would prefer to simply change the stored value before executing the query since I will have several of these queries to run using that value `lookup`.

Is there a way to do this? Any advice would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`glue` package](https://github.com/tidyverse/glue) which allows to easily embed R expressions in the query string using curly braces :

```
lookup <- '12345D%'

(qry <- glue::glue("SELECT *
     FROM tableX
     WHERE tableX.code LIKE '{lookup}';"))

# SELECT *
# FROM tableX
# WHERE tableX.code LIKE '12345D%';

query_df <- as.data.table(sqlQuery(myconn, qry))
```